# has_many :through vs straightforward belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am stuck with picking the correct model architecture for my application. A User can create Jobs (`JobRequest`), these jobs are being run on schedules, so every `JobRequest` has many runs (`JobRequestRun`). After each run, there's an output file (`OutputDataFile`) generated and attached to the `JobRequestRun` (only one file per run). I should be able to access these report files by calling either `JobRequest.output_data_files` or `JobRequestRun.output_data_file`. I cannot settle on a scheme I need:

```
JobRequest
  has_many output_data_files, through: job_request_runs

JobRequestRun
  belongs_to output_data_files
  belongs_to job_request

OutputDataFile
  has_many job_requests, through: job_request_runs

# OR

JobRequest
  has_many output_data_files
  has_many job_request_runs

JobRequestRun
  has_one output_data_file
  belongs_to job_request

OutputDataFile
  belongs_to job_request
  belongs_to job_request_run
```

Which one of these does make sense to you?

Comment: `has_many, through:` doesn't apply for your architecture because there is no ***many-to-many*** relation between `job_request` and `job_request_run` and `job_request_run` cannot be a join table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By your text description of your problem domain, this is what I came up with:

```
class JobRequest < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :job_request_runs
  has_many :output_data_files, through: :job_request_runs
end

class JobRequestRun < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :job_request
  has_one :output_data_file
end

class OutputDataFile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :job_request_run
  has_one :job_request, through: :job_request_run
end
```